# Whats going on in AWK with $$1?

Tags: awk

what's going on in AWK with $$? I have $$1~/^[^0-9]/ {print $$1;} and I don't understand it.

I have tried in compiler with that but I couldn't find any dependence.
std
1 ABC1724 2018 Wroclaw
3 ABC1724 2018 Wroclaw
2 ABC1724 2018 Wroclaw

Comment: What were you hoping that `$$1` would represent? [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable, sample input, expected output, and a **complete** script so we can help you. Regarding `I have tried in compiler with that but I couldn't find any dependence.` - I have no idea what that might mean. Awk's an interpreted language so what is it you're trying to compile and how and what does "dependence" mean in that context?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting then format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$1` should be understand as `$($1)` thus it is reading first field value, then getting that field, consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
2 B C D
4 B C D
3 B C D
```

then

```
awk '{print $$1}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
B
D
C
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*